# issues with getting multiple select param values from jquery, javascript back to perl cgi page

Tags: javascript, perl, jquery, cgi

I have been working on this for 1 hour with no such luck. Any help would be appreciated.

I have a cgi script with which creates these select param values:

```
print "Please select a dkversion to compare : <br><br>";
print "<select name='dkversion' id='dkversion' size='6' multiple='multiple'>";
foreach my $values ('ASDF123GS v0.01 models eval QA <-> apple', 'ZXCV534GS v1.01 models eval QA <-> pineapple')
{
    print "<option value=\"" . $values . "\" >" . $values  . "</option>";
}
print "</select>";
print "</form>";
```

I have another html page that uses jquery/javascript to process the inputs:

```
     var scalarstr = "";
     $("#dkversion :selected").each(function () {
        scalarstr += "dkselected=" + encodeURIComponent($(this).val()) + "&";
     });

     $.get("./scripts/modelQA_correlation.cgi?" +  scalarstr + "&menu_mode=2",function(data){ 
     });
```

Coming Back to cgi page to process the multiple selects, I do a dump of the inputs and noticed it isn't separating the values:

```
$VAR1 = { 'dkselected' => 'ASDF123GS v0.01 models eval QA <-> apple�ZXCV534GS v1.01 models eval QA <-> pineapple', 'menu_mode' => '2' };
```

Why isn't the dkselected values being separate into it's two parts??

Comment: It would help if you narrow down where this is happening: when you look at the URL, does the query string appear right?
Offhand I would guess that however you're processing the CGI arguments in Perl is not taking account of the multiple values of dkversion. If you're using the CGI.pm module, then param('dkversion') will be an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A safer approach here is to let jQuery encode the string, let's get the values from the `<select>`, store them in an array, via [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/), then add the `menu_mode` to it, like this:

```
var params = $("#dkversion").serializeArray()​;
params.push({ name: 'menu_mode', value: '2' });
$.get("./scripts/modelQA_correlation.cgi", params, function(data){ });​
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ZnXzw/1/).  This does everything your code above does, but I hope you'll agree much simpler and easier to maintain.  This works by passing an object as the [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) `data` option, which internally calls [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to get the final string, so you can test/see the result yourself like I have in the demo.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing something like `$args = CGI::Vars`, then you're running afoul of the quirk in how CGI.pm handles multiple values. [You'll need to split the string on `"\0"` (null).](http://p3rl.org/CGI#FETCHING_THE_PARAMETER_LIST_AS_A_HASH:)

Another approach is to use the param method: `@vals = $q->param('dkversion');`

Comment: everything about the coding was correct except i didn't save into @vals, i was thinking the data would have been processed in the hash but it wasn't ...